# Mixing multiple sources on Windows to different devices

Tags: windows, audio, windows-vista, streaming, audio-streaming

I've been looking out there and think there are a couple of solutions to this problem but I'm not sure exactly the best way to go about it.

On a Windows Vista PC I am trying to stream the output from two audio scanners/radios, and possibly an online stream. The scanners will either be connected to the left and right channels of the build in sound device, or one on the built in device and one on a usb sound card.

I want one stream to be just one scanner (a), and the other audio stream to be both scanners (a & b), on separate channels. The online stream would be combined with one scanner(a), again on separate channels.

We are using butt and icecast to stream. I have installed [VB Virtual Audio Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm), which works well with VLC and butt as an additional feed. I've also looked at Jack Audio.

One sticking point is having two output devices, mixing one input device (scanner a) with output device a and the left channel of output device b, and then having those output devices be the input to butt. That said, I think I can donate to VB-Audio and use the virtual cable for that.

Here's an attempt to describe the main goal:

[image: Pictorial Overview]